# Difference between Layer Definition File (qlr) and QGIS Layer Style File (qml)?

Tags: qgis-3

What is the difference between Layer Definition File (qlr) and QGIS Layer Style File (qml)? Which one is recommended?

I have only used qlr so far. It seems store all the data displayed in the "properties" of the layer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question is answered in a blog post by Nathan Woodrow: [What are all these QGIS file types? Why do I need them](https://nathanw.net/2014/03/22/all-the-q-files/)

Here's a summary:

- The QML file (.qml) contains style information
- The Layer Definition file (.qlr) contains a layer source pointer + style information

So you can drag a QLR file into a project, and it adds the layer with all its saved styling.

A QML file isn't tied to any specific data source.

Comment: The link to Nathan Woodrow is broken, so here is a link to the docs:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/qgis_file_formats.html

Comment: Link to the old blog post https://woostuff.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/all-the-q-files/ if you need to read the other posts there are located in that space as they haven't been migrated to his new site