# Export List of File Paths from QGIS

Tags: qgis

Can I export a list of layers and their associated file paths (like the pop-up when you open QGIS and links are missing) for all my layers within a QGIS Project?

I want my collegue to have a mirror image of the QGIS project I have created.

Also is there a way to copy all the styles and apply them to the same project on another computer?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the easiest would be to send the QGIS project file and get both paths and styles. Or try qlr files, I havent: [Difference between Layer Definition File (qlr) and QGIS Layer Style File (qml)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330532/difference-between-layer-definition-file-qlr-and-qgis-layer-style-file-qml)

But to export paths of all added layers you can use pyqgis to write them to a text file:

```
with open(r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\layerlist.txt','w') as f:
    for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        f.write(lyr.source()+'\n')
```

[image]

Comment: If you save the .qgz file and share it, relink all the layers when opening on the new PC you get a mirror. But there are no styles. So you have to go, Properties, Symbology, Styles, Load Style, Apply etc. time and time again. Is there no simple shortcut for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to export the whole project (files and styles) in a specif folder, that you can easily send to anyone, with the plugin "QPackage".

Another option could be to save the project files, styles and layers to a geopackage file, or it is possible to use a PostGIS database making it accessible from other PC.