# Saving orthomosaic .tiff data with symbolization changes using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, geotiff-tiff, ndvi, rgb

I changed the symbolization of my .tiff data such that the NDVI band (Band 1 (Gray)) is represented with 4 colors (RGB derived). Is there a way I can save the .tiff including the symbology changes? That way, when loading the layer in QGIS next time, it shows with the changes previously made.

QGIS version: QGIS 3.22.3 'Białowieża' on Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the `.tif` as a Layer Definition file (.qlr). Should be the third option if you right click on the layer and go to `export`. You will not be able to remove your original `.tif` because it is being used as the layer source. [Check out this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330532/difference-between-layer-definition-file-qlr-and-qgis-layer-style-file-qml):

Here's a summary:

The QML file (.qml) contains style information

- The Layer Definition file (.qlr) contains a layer source pointer + style information
- So you can drag a QLR file into a project, and it adds the layer with all its saved styling.

A QML file isn't tied to any specific data source.